# Prove that limit = 0.

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

So the question is as in the title.

$$\lim_{(x,y,z)\to (0,0,0)}\frac{\sin(xyz)}{\sqrt{(x^2+y^2+z^2)}}$$

I decided to prove it from the definition.

so $L = 0$

$$\left\lvert\frac{\sin(xyz)}{\sqrt{(x^2+y^2+z^2)}}-0 \right \rvert \leq \frac {1}{\sqrt{(x^2+y^2+z^2)}} $$

and then trnasform it to this
$${\frac{\sqrt{(x^2+y^2+z^2)}}{x^2+y^2+z^2}}$$
and now i don't know what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bounding the sine with $1$ is brutal: you are losing a lot, so much that you get something that does not go to zero. Rather,
$$
\frac{|\sin(xyz)|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\leq \frac{|xyz|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}
=|xy|\frac{|z|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\leq|xy|.
$$

Answer (score 3):

Use $|\sin t|\le|t|$. Then
$$\left|\frac{\sin(xyz)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\right|
\le\left|\frac{xyz}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\right|.$$
If we let $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ then $|xyz|\le r^3$ etc.